# How to search whether more than one lines exist after a certain string?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that generates following output:

```
URL:
 http://framework.com

Name(s):
 Patching Framework
----------------------------------------------------------

URL:
 http://asjkdfhn.com

Name(s):
 jadsbfkjdfhn dsjfkh
----------------------------------------------------------

URL:
 http://wusdh.com

Name(s):
 Wholesale Underwear dark health
----------------------------------------------------------
URL:
 http://wertyuiioofn.com

Name(s):
 werthyeshfd asjfdhn
 ajdsfbndjfb dsjfhndjfhn
 dkfmdkfm dkfjkdjf
----------------------------------------------------------

URL:
 http://google.com

Name(s):
 Google
 Google, Phillipines
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to print/echo only those URLs/Name(s) which have more than one names listed.

Example: From above URLs/Name(s), only following to be printed:

```
URL:
 http://wertyuiioofn.com

Name(s):
 werthyeshfd asjfdhn
 ajdsfbndjfb dsjfhndjfhn
 dkfmdkfm dkfjkdjf
----------------------------------------------------------

URL:
 http://google.com

Name(s):
 Google
 Google, Phillipines
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to do using bash/shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Add your filename after this command:

```
sed -n '
       /URL:/{
              :addanotherrow
              N
              /-\{50,\}/bmatchandprint
              baddanotherrow
              :matchandprint
              /Name(s):[^\n]*\n[^-\n]*\n[^-]/p
              }
       '
```

Some explanations:

> - the sed parameter "-n" prevents automatic printing of pattern space - the matched patterns are printed with the "p" at the end of the last row of the
>     statements inside the brackets {}
> - labels are marked with a leading ":", so ":addanotherrow" and ":matchandprint" are jumping points for the "b" statements
> - b followed by a label is a command to branch to that label (something like a GOTO)
> - N appends the next line of input into the pattern space
> - lines starting with "/" just proof the pattern space against a regular expression, when the regex fits, the following command is executed,
>     as already mentioned the b branches and the p prints the pattern space

In other words: the string "URL:" is searched, from that point more rows are included until a line (at least 50 hyphens in a row) was found. After that the gathered rows ("pattern space") are examined. Only when a "Name(s):" with more than one row (that is not beginning with a hyphen) was found, the pattern space will be printed.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work properly. It prints everything that exists on the file.

Comment: I had tested it successfully with your provided test data. Copy and paste the "output" data from your question into a file and make a test run.

Comment: I checked again, it works. Can you please explain how it works? What does each line do exactly?

Comment: Added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sed -n '
       /URL:/{
              :1                          #return point
              N                           #append next line
              /-{20,}/!b1                 #go to return point while reach ---
              /Name(s):\n[^\n]\+\n[^-]/p  #check if more 1 line after «Name(s)»  
              }
       '
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't do anything. Doesn't return any results.

Comment: @Koshur suppose you pass output of your script via pipe to above code? `./your.script | sed -n '…` Other thing is `-` symbol: Try to copy|paste it from the output to sed script.